# Pyspark Group by Id only consecutive occurrences

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, aggregate, grouping

I have this dataframe:

| Id | Minute | identifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 1 | 1 |
| aa | 1 | 2 |
| aa | 1 | 3 |
| aa | 2 (ignore) | 4 |
| aa | 1 | 5 |
| aa | 1 | 6 |
| bb | 1 | 7 |
| bb | 1 | 8 |
| bb | 5 (ignore) | 9 |
| bb | 1 | 10 |

My desired output is grouped by "Id", but sum consecutive "Minute" (only when they are = 1):

| Id | Minute |
| --- | --- |
| aa | 3 |
| aa | 2 |
| bb | 2 |
| bb | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using window functions. They must be used twice: to create helper column for grouping and then to create groups. Then, group rows according to created groups.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('aa', 1, 1),
     ('aa', 1, 2),
     ('aa', 1, 3),
     ('aa', 2, 4),
     ('aa', 1, 5),
     ('aa', 1, 6),
     ('bb', 1, 7),
     ('bb', 1, 8),
     ('bb', 5, 9),
     ('bb', 1, 10)],
    ['Id', 'Minute', 'identifier'])
```

Script:

```py
w = W.partitionBy('Id').orderBy('identifier')
df = df.withColumn('_flg', F.coalesce(F.when(F.lag("Minute").over(w) != F.col("Minute"), 1), F.lit(0)))
df = df.withColumn('_grp', F.sum('_flg').over(w))
df = (df
    .filter(F.col('Minute') == 1)
    .groupBy('Id', '_grp')
    .agg(F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('Minute'))
    .drop('_grp')
)
df.show()
# +---+------+
# | Id|Minute|
# +---+------+
# | aa|     3|
# | aa|     2|
# | bb|     2|
# | bb|     1|
# +---+------+
```